# Brackets in javascript background url

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem with a plugin I am using, where I need to assign a background through jquery.

I get the following url back from the database:

```
http://www.website.com/upload/projects/25/opbouw_(10)_(800x600).jpg
```

And it is not displaying this image because of the brackets in the url.
I can not change this url because a client hast uploaded it. Before you point out the security issues about this: I did not wrote it and I can not change it either. So I'll have to deal with this, unfortunately.

I have found a similar question about spaces in a javascript url, but you can use `encodeURIComponent` and `encodeURI` to solve that problem, however, the `()` are unescaped characters and will not be formatted properly.

My question is, what am I supposed to do to make sure the image shows properly? Some kind of Regex? (I suck at Regex btw).

Thanks! :-)

Edit:

some javascript code...

```
iw.css({'background-image':'url('+ent.data("src")+')','backgroundPosition':'50% 49%', 'backgroundSize':'cover', 'background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
```

`ent.data("src")` is the url I get back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "correct" way to define a background image is like so:

```
url("/path/to/image.jpg")
```

Note the use of quotes. People always seem to forget the quotes... They are optional in most cases, but as seen here they are required for proper parsing. Add them.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is asking

Comment: Because you aren't using quotes. If you had quotes, the parentheses in the URL wouldn't be a problem ;)

Comment: Namely, `{'background-image':'url("'+ent.data("src")+'")',...}`

Comment: You have to give this thing 7 minutes, Stackoverflow is slow to accept an answer :P I am apperently stupid enough to miss brackets tho! If it helps, I didn't write the javascript plugin, bought it and would expect something stupid like this be implemented :-) Sorry!

Comment: You could've at least commented or something :p No hard feelings, but just be aware that we all make dumb mistakes and the first step is to accept that sometimes you might have missed the obvious ;)